# How to use AverageTimer32 and AverageBase performance counters with System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch?

Tags: c#, .net, performancecounter

When I execute the following program and look at the performance counter the results don't make sense to me.  The average value is zero and the min/max values are ~0.4 when I would expect ~0.1 or ~100.

What is my problem?

**Code**

```
class Program
{
    const string CategoryName = "____Test Category";
    const string CounterName = "Average Operation Time";
    const string BaseCounterName = "Average Operation Time Base";

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        if (PerformanceCounterCategory.Exists(CategoryName))
            PerformanceCounterCategory.Delete(CategoryName);

        var counterDataCollection = new CounterCreationDataCollection();

        var avgOpTimeCounter = new CounterCreationData()
        {
            CounterName = CounterName,
            CounterHelp = "Average Operation Time Help",
            CounterType = PerformanceCounterType.AverageTimer32
        };
        counterDataCollection.Add(avgOpTimeCounter);

        var avgOpTimeBaseCounter = new CounterCreationData()
        {
            CounterName = BaseCounterName,
            CounterHelp = "Average Operation Time Base Help",
            CounterType = PerformanceCounterType.AverageBase
        };
        counterDataCollection.Add(avgOpTimeBaseCounter);

        PerformanceCounterCategory.Create(CategoryName, "Test Perf Counters", PerformanceCounterCategoryType.SingleInstance, counterDataCollection);

        var counter = new PerformanceCounter(CategoryName, CounterName, false);
        var baseCounter = new PerformanceCounter(CategoryName, BaseCounterName, false);

        for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++)
        {
            var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            Thread.Sleep(100);
            sw.Stop();

            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("t({0}) ms({1})", sw.Elapsed.Ticks, sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds));
            counter.IncrementBy(sw.Elapsed.Ticks);
            baseCounter.Increment();
        }

        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

**Performance Counter Screenshot**
[Performance Counter Screenshot http://friendfeed-media.com/50028bb6a0016931a3af5122774b56f93741bb5c](http://friendfeed-media.com/50028bb6a0016931a3af5122774b56f93741bb5c)

Comment: Could you change the URL of the screenshot please to use StackOverflow's standard?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The System.Diagnostics API contains a pretty subtle source of great confusion: System.Diagnostics 'ticks' are not the same as DateTime or TimeSpan 'ticks'!

If you use [StopWatch.ElapsedTicks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.elapsedticks.aspx) instead of StopWatch.Elapsed.Ticks, it should work.

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.elapsedticks.aspx) contains more information about this.

Answer (score 9):

Mark Seemann explained the confusing source of the problem but I would like to provide a little bit of additional information.

If you want to set your `AverageTimer32` performance counter from a `TimeSpan` and not a `Stopwatch` you can perform the following conversion:

```
var performanceCounterTicks = timeSpan.Ticks*Stopwatch.Frequency/TimeSpan.TicksPerSecond;
averageTimerCounter.IncrementBy(performanceCounterTicks);
averageTimerCounterBase.Increment();
```

Comment: Why do you need casting unchecked((Int32)...) ? performanceCounterTicks is evaluated as long, all the values are actually long numbers.

Comment: @DavideIcardi: Thanks, you are right that the signature of the `IncrementBy` method accepts an `Int64` so there is no need to perform a cast. I have removed the cast from the code.

Comment: `TimeSpan.TicksPerSecond` is probably more future-and-platform-proof to use instead of hard-coding the value.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old thread, but I thought I'd chime in.  I was told by someone from Microsoft that I shouldn't use `TimeSpan`, `StopWatch`, or `DateTime` when working with Performance Counters.  Instead, he recommended adding the following native method to my project:

```
internal static class NativeMethods
{
    [DllImport("Kernel32.dll")]
    public static extern void QueryPerformanceCounter(ref long ticks); 
}
```

When incrementing a counter, he recommended doing so like this:

```
public void Foo()
{
    var beginTicks = 0L;

    var endTicks = 0L;

    NativeMethods.QueryPerformanceCounter(ref beginTicks);

    // Do stuff

    NativeMethods.QueryPerformanceCounter(ref endTicks);

    this.Counter.IncrementBy(endTicks - beginTicks);
    this.BaseCounter.Increment();
}
```

Comment: Did he also give a reason for that? `StopWatch` is just a wrapper over `QueryPerformanceCounter` (with a fallback if it's not available). If `StopWatch.IsHighResolution` is true, `StopWatch.GetTimeStamp()` is equivalent to `QueryPerformanceCounter`.

Comment: He cited a Microsoft Patterns and Practices book about Performance.  His reasoning was that you wanted as little overhead as possible when performing the same action many times.  Performance Counters may be incremented many times per second.  By using a StopWatch, you're instantiating a StopWatch object each time you want to measure the performance of a method and increment the counter.  These Stopwatch objects must then be garbage collected.  By calling `QueryPerformanceCounter` directly, you cut out the middle-man and save the construction and collection of the Stopwatch object.

Comment: `StopWatch.GetTimeStamp()` is a static method and a thin wrapper over `QueryPerformanceCounter`. The only extra cost is a branch on a static field that doesn't change over time, so branch prediction should work pretty well.