# How to get average value constantly using performance counter?

Tags: c#, performancecounter

I am getting the RAM and CPU usage of my PC every second using 1 event handler each that is updating this information. I am directing this information to be printed in a `TextBox`. It is working fine.

On top of this, I am trying to constantly update the average RAM and average CPU usage. As in after the program has run for 10 seconds, I get the average value by adding the last 10 seconds' RAM values and dividing them by 10. Same for 11 seconds where I divide by 11 secs and so on.

I figure I would need to constantly count the seconds and constantly add the ram count and CPU usage count. I am currently using Performance counter to get the CPU and RAM values.

Can I use the performance counter to get the average too? Please advise. My code is as follows.

```
class Perform
{
    private PerformanceCounter cpuCounter;
    private PerformanceCounter ramCounter;

    public Perform()
    {
        cpuCounter = new PerformanceCounter("Processor", "% Processor Time", "_Total");
        ramCounter = new PerformanceCounter("Memory", "Available MBytes");
    }

    public float GetCurrentCpuUsage()
    {
        return cpuCounter.NextValue();
    }

    public float GetCurrentAvailableRam()
    {
        return ramCounter.NextValue();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this of any help? : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1547179/how-to-use-averagetimer32-and-averagebase-performance-counters-with-system-diagn

Comment: I did read that post. It uses stopwatch. I am trying to see if everything can be donw within performance counter.

Comment: I couldn't find any kind of performance counter or settings that will let you get the average, so you might have to keep track of a set number of values and calculate the average yourself.